# Launch an emacsclient instance in a new terminal window

Tags: frames, emacsclient, terminal-emacs, emacs-daemon

I am using Sway/wlroots and I decided to switch to using terminal emacs for the forseeable future as there is no transparency in the xwayland version of emacs.

I previously bound emacs to run as a client to connect to my emacs daemon like so `emacsclient -c -n -e '(switch-to-buffer nil)'` so that upon a sway keystroke it will open a new emacsframe/window.

Basically, how do I do this with `emacsclient -nw`? my terminal of choice is `termite` and so i tried to replace the above with this `termite -e 'emacsclient -nw'` but emacs gets into a locked up state or doesnt launch at all.

Here's the error I get from invoking the previous command from another terminal:

```
me@laptop ~ % termite -e 'emacsclient -nw'
invalid color string: #

(termite:30425): GLib-WARNING **: 12:46:32.770: GChildWatchSource: Exit status of a child process was requested but ECHILD was received by waitpid(). See the documentation of g_child_watch_source_new() for possible causes.
```

I thought it may be something to do with the client/server config since launching a new emacs like this: `termite -e 'emacs -nw'` works as expected, although still spits out the same error above.

Comment: You can try adding a `&` at the end of the command to launch it asynchronously, and you might want to redirect stdout and stderr somewhere else to keep the terminal clean.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your command `termite -e 'emacsclient -nw'` works fine when run from a terminal, but fails when you bind it to a key in your Sway config? This works fine for me with i3 and gnome-terminal, so I suspect the problem is with termite or Sway, not Emacs. Can you try using other terminals - gnome-terminal or xterm etc?

Comment: @Tyler `termite -e 'emacsclient -nw'` did **not** work, `termite -e 'emacs -nw'` did. the former launched in a terminal or in sway/i3 produce the same result, a window is created but quickly disappears, with that warning.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 thank you, launching it async **seems** to work,

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 Sorry I thought i finished my post before but i left off with a comma.  I got something to work with you original advice, first tried `termite -e 'emacsclient -nw &'` but it only worked once and opened the buffer named &. looking back at the emacsclient args, it thinks `&` is a file. so i added a `.` like `termite -e 'emacsclient -nw . &'` and it seems to work as intended, except after opening several more emacsclient panes it says `File no longer exists: /home/revive/&, write buffer to file?` So it must not be launching asynchronously like so either.

Comment: Also, if I close one of those panes, it seems to lock up the rest and i have to restart the whole emacs daemon.  I suppose this method won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a command from a shell asynchronously by adding an `&` at the end of it, which in your case would mean running a command like `termite -e 'emacsclient -nw' &`.

You might also try binding the command (without the `&`) to some key in your window manager, or run it from some run utility. You'll want to keep the invocation of the terminal emulator in place, as Emacs won't figure that part on its own.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as expected either. At first glance, it appears to open as many panes with emacsclient as needed, but if I attempt to `kill` a sway/i3 window with one of them by using the macro such as `Mod+Shift+Q` instead of closing the emacsclient the emacs way `C - x C - c`, all other emacsclients freeze and I am forced to kill the emacs daemon. Both ways close the window immediately, but only the emacs way exits gracefully. Also, it puts my emacsdaemon's CPU usage at 100%

Comment: Also when using this method after mucking around with opening and closing new windows,  upon trying any key macros I get the emacs message `Wrong type argument: terminal-live-p, #<Frame F5 0x456ed50>`

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with your init file. Have you tried running Emacs without it?

Comment: Well I that seems to solve it.  Thats a shame, because the GUI emacs works fine. And my .emacs.el file is some 2000 lines =(

Comment: You can use binary search to find the culprit.